# Progress Bar for YuoTube video Downloads Using youtube-dl FINISHED

Tags: php

I am using
$cmd = 'youtube-dl '. $url. " > yt-dl-progress.txt";
shell_exec($cmd);

to download a YouTube video.  I want to get access to the logfile during the down load so that I can create a download progress bar but I can only access its data after the down load is complet.  Is there any way I can get the data from the file during the actual download every second or so?

Comment: PHP doesn't really do async or threads so probably not, no